# How to check arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ support for C++11

Tags: c++, gcc, arm, cross-compiling

I am writing an portable application which uses `C++11` features like `std::atomic`, `std::threads`, etc. How do I verify that my ARM GCC cross compiler toolchain supports the `C++11` standard?

I tried using `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -v` 
and `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ --version`
but it returned error when using `-std=c++11`

**EDIT** # arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -std=c++11 dum.cpp

cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option '-std=c++11'

Target: arm-linux-gnueabi

gcc version 4.6.2

Comment: Sorry, my crystal ball is absolutely silent about the error you got. Care to share it? ;)

Comment: @syam Added the compiler error message!

Comment: Yeah well GCC 4.6 didn't support the `-std=c++11` flag since it was released before the C++11 standard was published, but `-std=c++0x` was supported. However you might find that GCC 4.6 doesn't fit your requirements. Your best bet would be to determine the minimal GCC version you need (with respect to the features you use) and enforce it in your `configure.ac` script. Note however that only GCC 4.8 has full C++11 core language support, but it doesn't even have full library support yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [cxx0x support matrix](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).  ARM Linux supports most features in a standard way.  It is possible that a particular machine may not support a feature.  Ie, the *gcc* version, *linux* version and *glibc* version and CPU type could all come into play.

Test the define `__VERSION__` to see if the compiler can support it.  Very, very old Linux versions may have no way to support this with some CPU types; ARMv5 and older.  Newer ARM CPUs have some bus locking instructions and can support this with out any or little OS support.

```
echo | g++ -dM -E - | grep -i atomic
```

Should give a list of defines.  If you compile with `-march=armv7`, you will have the most luck.  However, with more recent Linux versions (and compiler/glibc targeting this version), even the `-march=armv5` will work on non-SMP systems.  I don't think an ARMv5 SMP system can exist.

As you can see there are many working parts and it is possible that some features may only be known to work at run time.  It is probably impossible to provide a list; you need a **gcc** version with at least the support matrix for it to be possible that the feature works.

For example, with the same compiler but only `-march=armv4` versus `-march=armv6`,

### armv4

```
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR32_T_LOCK_FREE 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE 1
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE 1
```

### armv6

```
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_CHAR32_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_POINTER_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_INT_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_WCHAR_T_LOCK_FREE 2
#define __GCC_ATOMIC_LONG_LOCK_FREE 2
```

Most modern smart phones with have **armv7** or better.

Comment: Err, if the *atomics* are not support then the library can always fall-back to mutex/semaphore behavior.  But then you are not getting what is advertised.  Typically this slow behavior will be on the slowest devices!  On all ARM CPUs, we can lock interrupts and have *user space* atomic emulation.

Comment: Actually, a surprisingly large number of what is dubbed 'landfill android' - the kind of cheap smartphone that turns up in supermarkets on PAYG deals - are actually single core ARMv6. These sell in surprisingly large volumes, but luckily, mostly to people who didn't really want a smartphone in the first place.  Beware.

Comment: Does arm cortex a90 support c++11? how can i understand?